# find text in one file and replace with text from another file SED or AWK

Tags: awk, sed, find, replace

Ubuntu 18 build

I am trying to find this text, `[define( 'AUTH_KEY',]` without `[]` in `/var/www/file1.txt`, and then copy the line and replace the same line in `/var/www/file2.php`. I have tried multiple options with `sed` and `awk` with no success.

```bsh
awk '/"define\( 'AUTH_KEY',"/' /var/www/file1.txt > /var/www/file2.php
```

```bsh
sed -i 's/"define\( 'AUTH_KEY',"/' /var/www/file1.txt >> /var/www/file2.php
```

`file1.txt` contains the line

```
define('AUTH_KEY',         '{++X!upib~T.#C.&ykXDQpQ<nyrD7jadfu*adk^);
```

`file2.php` contains the line

```
define( 'AUTH_KEY',         'put your unique phrase here' );
```

I need the line from `file1.txt` to replace the same line in `file2.php`.

Comment: Why not just manually replace it? By asking a question like this, it implies you want to be able to batch the change for multiple files. If that's the case, then some kind of templating engine would be the natural approach, not sed/awk.

Comment: I want to run the script on multiple files with multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '
  /define\([ \t]*\047AUTH_KEY\047,/{ 
    if (FNR==NR){ line=$0 }
    else{ $0=line }
  }
  FNR!=NR
' /var/www/file1.txt /var/www/file2.php > /var/www/file2.php.new
mv /var/www/file2.php.new /var/www/file2.php
```

The bracket expression `[ \t]` matches a space or tab character, the `*` matches the pattern zero or more times.
`\047` is a octal single quote `'`.

When the first file is processed, save the matched record in variable `line`. When the second file is processed, replace the matched record with the content of `line`.

`FNR!=NR` prints the records of the second file.

Comment: Always use octal `\047`, not hex `\x27`, ASCII code for `'`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote

Comment: Oh man, another quirk, thanks @EdMorton, changed it.
It looks like this issue is already fixed in `gawk`? I couldn't reproduce the ```awk 'BEGIN{print "\x27foo!\x27"}'``` example, only the `--posix` option doesn't like hex strings.

Comment: yeah, I thought I heard something about gawk handling it differently now but obviously that's just one of many awk variants and AFAIK there's no benefit to `\x27` over `\047`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an option:

```bsh
# save the AUTH_KEY into a variable
$ key=$(awk -F"'" '/AUTH_KEY/ { print $4 }' file1.txt)

# use the variable to replace the same value in the other file
$ awk -F"'" -v val="'${key//\\/\\\\}'" 'BEGIN { OFS="" } $4 = val,$2 = "'\''"$2"'\''"' file2.php

$ cat file2.php | grep AUTH_KEY
define(  'AUTH_KEY',          '{++X!upib~T.#C.&ykXDQpQ<nyrD7jadfu*adk^'  );
```

Comment: idk if it can happen or not but that'd fail if `key` contained a backslash.

Comment: @EdMorton Edited the answer, with a tentative solution to the problem you mention.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't expect that, not sure if there are any caveats. Normally you'd just use `ENVIRON[]` or pass the value in as an argument to have it treated as a literal string - see [how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)

Comment: I just noticed you're using `'` as the FS and I thought you were testing for `$2` being equal to a string that contains `'` which would never succeed but now I see you're not doing that at all - you're setting `$4` to whatever value `val` has and setting `$2` to the value it already has but enclosed in `"'"`s, doing that for every input line no matter what each line contains, and printing all lines since they're all within the range expression `$4=...,$2=...`. I don't think that's what you were trying to do as it'd modify every input line no matter what it is.

Comment: I think you probably mean to write something like `$4 == val{ $2 = "'\''"$2"'\''" } 1` but idk if that's correct or not. Using `'\''` for `'` will only work on the command-line btw while `\047` will work everywhere so it's a better option.

Answer (score 0):

```
base='/var/www'
tmpf=$(mktemp)
f1="$base/file1.txt"
f2="$base/file2.php"

ws='[[:blank:]]\{1,\}'
re_bre="define[(]$ws'AUTH_KEY'"

sed -e "/$re_bre/q;d" "$f1" |
sed -e "1h;/$re_bre/g;1d" - "$f2" > "$tmpf" &&
mv -f -- "$tmpf" "$f2"
```